# Question about arc-connected property in a continuum

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Suppose $X$ is metric, compact, connected, and $p\in X$.

An arc is a copy of $[0,1]$.

Is it possible that every two points in $X\setminus \{p\}$ can be joined by an arc, but there is no arc in $X$ containing $p$?

Comment: You may want to exclude the trivial arc at $p$: that is, $f:[0,1]\to X$ with $f(t)=p$ for all $t$.

Comment: That's not what I mean.  Regardless of how many large the space is, the function defined above is an arc containing $p$.

Comment: "An arc is a copy of $[0,1]$" is somewhat imprecise. Nowhere is requested that the map $f:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ is injective.

Comment: An arc in $X$  is an injective continuous map of $[0,1]$ into $X.$

Comment: Aside from singletons, are there compact connected metric spaces which are path-connected but not arc-connected?  Is it possible your problem is the same as asking "Is there a compact connected metric space $X$ and a point $p\in X$ so that $X-p$ is path-connected but $X$ isn't?"

Comment: @you Yes that is equivalent - path-connected and arc-connected are equivalent in Hausdorff spaces. See Exercise 6.3.12 in Engelking.

Comment: Ok cool.  I found a space where they're different notions, but it's not Hausdorff (hence not metric).  I also thought of another non-compact example: take the graph of $sin(1/x)$ for $x\in (0,1]$, along with the origin 0 (instead of a whole vertical bar).  Then you can show this is not path-connected in the same way as you show the topologist's sine curve is not path-connected, and if you remove 0 it becomes path-connected, but of course it's not compact.

Comment: Why couldn't the arcs $A_i$ all contain points well away from $p$?

Comment: The proposed proof strategy will not work. The remainder of a metrizable compactification of $[0, \infty)$ is connected, but need not be path-connected. On the contrary, it seems that every metrizable continuum is the remainder of a metrizable compactification of $[0, 1)$.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen yes, that is true! (and a fairly recent result I think)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes". See the example in my answer of [Path connectedness of one point compactification](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2800158). There exists a closed  arcwise connected subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that the one-point compactifaction $X^+$ is not pathwise connected.

Comment: Thank you for the update; I am very intrigued and will read your answer sometime this evening.